# Android: Press Done Button on Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-activity, appium

Using appium for android app automation. Not able to click on the "Done" button displayed on the phone keyboard. Can someone help is there any way we can click on the Android phone done button using ADB Shell commands?

Comment: Have your tried with `KEYCODE_ENTER`? `adb shell input keycode 66` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)

Comment: Yes tried, it doesn't work, it's for Enter...I'm looking for Done button..

Comment: It should be this one then: `FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)

Comment: what's the adb command for FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION? I tried "adb shell input keyevent FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION" but looks like not working

Comment: It's `adb shell input keycode 16`. In the `KeyEvent` documentation page, you will see a **Constant Value: XX (0x000YYYYY)** statement for each entry. In this case, XX is the desired value to type.

Comment: Even KEYCODE_9 is having constant value of 16, so when i entering the adb command with value 16 it's pressing the '9' key on the keyboard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no constructive way to click on the Done or Next button on the device keyboard. So as a temporary solution I'm tapping with 2 fingers on the Done button coordinates, However this is not a viable solution to do this. Will wait until appium comes with fix for this in next version.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to implement your solution? or is it just a manual action of tapping with 2 fingers?

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you can not directly click on keypad keys until you use Appium coordinates to perform click/tap action which is not always reliable. But you can simulate Hardware keys on android using Appium.

To press(simulate) Done button, use the below code:

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

Answer (score 2):

As indirect solution I use key_event TAB (61) to switch focus to action button then I send key_event ENTER (66)

```
adb shell input keyevent 61
```

Then:

```
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Pixel 3, I've automated tapping the Search/Next/Done button using adb via this command:

```
adb shell input tap 1070 1940
```

The x,y coordinates will vary based on your device. The get a rough sense of where to start, you can use adb to determine your screen size, and then move in and up from the lower-right corner. So, on my Pixel 3, I used this adb command to determine window size:

```
adb shell wm size
```

That gave me this output: "Physical size: 1080x2160". I moved ten pixels in from the right and 180 up from the bottom to get the "1070 1940" x,y coordinates that work for me.

So now I can enter a search string into a text field and emulate tapping the search key on the soft keyboard with something like this:

```
adb shell input text searchterm && adb shell input tap 1070 1940
```

This is all necessary because the search box I'm using is an Android EditText with this XML attribute to indicate that the standard Enter key should be replaced with a search icon:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

If that weren't the case, I believe I could just send the standard KeyEvent for the Enter key:

```
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

With the IME search option enabled, I believe you would have to send KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER (i.e., 66) along with FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION (which has a mask value of 16), but it does not appear that adb shell input supports the addition of flags.

I've tried sending KEYCODE_SEARCH (i.e., 84), which has been present in the Android API since version 1, but that doesn't work on the application I'm testing. Not sure why.