# adb- Is there a way to simulate IME_ACTION _DONE?

Tags: android, adb, calabash-android

Can you simulate IME_ACTION_DONE commands on the adb shell?

I have used this but it does not work

```
adb shell input ime IME_ACTION_DONE
```

I am trying to use this system command on my calabash test by running the above command using the system function

Comment: To solve that , I send key_event TAB (61) then enter (66) see my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170667/2267723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Calabash-Android method `press_user_action_button` to simulate these interactions. Notice that your application should still handle enter keys (e.g. `press_enter_button`) as some phones will have a physical or bluetooth keyboard connected.